# How to create an object of class property of type List<class>

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, class, generics

I have following classes in my wcf:

```
[DataContract]
public class CibilEnquiry
{
    public PN Pn { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<ID> Id { get; set; }  
}



[DataContract]
public class ID
{
    [DataMember]
    public string SegmentTag { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string IDType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string IDNumber { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class PN
{
    [DataMember]
    public string SegmentTag { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ConsumerNameField1 { get; set; }   
}
```

I am trying to create object in ym application :

```
CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry CibilEnquiryEnq = new CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry();//no problem

CibilEnquiryEnq.Pn = new CibilWcfService.PN();//no problem
CibilEnquiryEnq.Id  = new CibilWcfService.ID() ;//Cannot implicitly convert type 'CbilFileReader.CibilWcfService.ID' to 'CbilFileReader.CibilWcfService.ID[]'
```

As I have mentioned in the comment I am unable to create objects of those properties of CibilEnquiry which are of type List.

Also, it seems that when i initialize properties using constructor in wcf its of no use. (already asked that one here :[Unable to initialize member through Constructor in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752947/unable-to-initialize-member-through-constructor-in-wcf)).

Comment: This code won't even compile, as `CibilEnquiryEnq` has no property called `Pa`, did you mean `CibilEnquiryEnq.Id = new CibilWcfService.PA() ;`?

Comment: The error is pretty clear:  You're trying to create a single instance of the object and assign it directly to a property that is an array type. You need to create an array, stick the new instance inside that, and assign the array to the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is self describing, you can not assign an instance of `ID` to an `ID[]` array at this line:

```
CibilEnquiryEnq.Id  = new CibilWcfService.ID()
```

Pay attention that you have declared `Id` this way `public List<ID> Id { get; set; }` and when you added service reference, the service reference utility converted it to `public ID[] Id { get; set; }` in `CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry` type.

To assign an instance of an array to `Id` you can use this:

```
CibilEnquiryEnq.Id = new CibilWcfService.ID[]{};
```

To initialize your array with some values, you can create the array with the size you need and then in a `for` loop create an instance of `ID` and initialize it and assign it to `array[i]` and at last use `CibilEnquiryEnq.Id= array`

Also you can use a `List<ID>` and create and add some `ID` to it using `list.Add()` and then convert the list to array and assign it this way:  `CibilEnquiryEnq.Id= list.ToArray()`

Comment: Why did it convert it into array when it was a list? Your code works but I would like to be able to add instances dynamically in a loop.

Comment: @Arbaaz You can add items dynamically in loop to array as well, there is no problem.

Comment: @Arbaaz **Why did it convert it into array when it was a list?**, you can configure service reference tool too use generic list for your list, you can remove your service reference, add service reference again, choose advanced , set collection type to `System.Collections.Generic.List`

Comment: What can I do in this scenario? 
 for (int i = 0; i < datatable.rows.count ; i++)
                {
                    CibilWcfService.ID id = new CibilWcfService.ID();

                    id.SegmentTag = datatable.rows[i][column1"].ToString();
                    id.IDType  = datatable.rows[i][column2"].ToString();
                    id.IDNumber =  datatable.rows[i][column3"].ToString();
                }

Comment: I know you can do this using a `List<Id>`, so do it the same way, and at last set `CibilEnquiryEnq.Id= list.ToArray()`

Comment: Or create an array with length of `datatable.Rows.Count` and in the loop create new `ID` and assign it to `array[i]`

Comment: Yea it worked. Please add this in your answer so i can mark it as answer. Also can you tell me how can i loop through datatable and assign the list if i  `I set collection type to System.Collections.Generic.List` ?

Comment: @Arbaaz Updated the answer.

Comment: @Arbaaz Let me know if you find the answer helpful or if you have any question about the answer :)

Comment: @Arbaaz While you are reading data from a WCF service, why you want to fill that property using a data table? Anyway [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33111563/3110834) is one of my answers about filling a list<T> using data table.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what `CibilWcfService.ID()` returns. If it returns `ID` then why do you declare your property as `public List<ID> Id { get; set; }`? Maybe it will be better if you just change this declratation?

If you really need to assign single record to a list then you can do like this:

```
CibilEnquiryEnq.Id = new List<ID> { CibilWcfService.ID() };
```